# What episode of Pokemon Diamond and Pearl does Brock state that can tell the difference between Joys?

Tags: pokemon

I know there is an episode of Diamond and Pearl where Brock states that he can tell Nurse Joys apart via the length of their hair and eyelashes, but I can’t remember what episode it was. There is a bet going on between my friends, help.

Answer (score 4):

Brock demonstrates his ability to differentiate Jennys and Joys on several occasions.

> **Officer Jenny:** *And I'm Jenny from Jubilife City, and my sister is the Officer Jenny from Sandgem Town!*
>
> **Dawn:** *Your sister?! You must be identical twins!*
>
> **Brock:** *Of course they're not identical! Talk about rude! It's obvious the length of their hair and eyelashes is not the same! Ahh. Not to mention that unique fragrance you're wearing....Of course, I could be wrong.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Setting the World on its Buneary!](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/DP009) - Diamond and Pearl</sup></sub>

and

> **Nurse Joy:** *Oh!*
>
> **Brock:** *Ah. It's completely obvious. I can tell the difference. Your
> bangs are a millimeter longer.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Setting the World on its Buneary!](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/DP009) - Diamond and Pearl</sup></sub>

and

> **Brock:** *Ah, well, hello, there. I see your eyelashes are 1/10 of an inch longer than any other Jenny in the country.*
>
> <sub><sup>[A Poached Ego!](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/AG006) - Ruby and Sapphire</sup></sub>

and

> **Brock:** *Awesome. Those were some of my top favorite Officer Jennies.*
>
> **Misty:** *You can tell them apart?*
>
> **Brock:** *Of course I can! Jenny from Viridian City [wears her skirt shorter than the other Jennies!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxCBV.png) The Celadon City Jenny uses styling
> gel in her luxurious hair! Saffron City's Jenny wears exotic Vileplume
> No. 5 perfume! Then there's the vivacious Vermillion City Jenny.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Round One - Begin! - Pokémon: Indigo League](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/EP075)</sup></sub>